# How different are the US and UK versions of Being Human?

Tags: being-human, being-human-us

I've watched the [UK version of *Being Human*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1349938/), and I'm curious about the [US version](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1595680/).  If they are different shows with the same basic concept, then I'll probably watch the the US series as well - but if it's just a remake of the same plot, then I'm not that interested.

How much overlap is there between the two series?  e.g.

- Almost nothing: same core character names, same concept (vampire, ghost, werewolf living together)
- As above, plus main season arcs.
- As above, plus many episode plots.

Obviously there will be stylistic differences between the two, so there's no need to point those out.  Also, unless you need to in order to explain the above, please forgo commenting on the relative (and subjective) quality.

I'd appreciate spoiler tags (start a line with >!) or leaving out major spoilers for the US version, but spoilers for the UK version are fine.

Answer (score 5):

I could spend hours answering this question. The US version is actually a lot more in depth regarding the characters and the plot. Though the pilot of the UK version actually becomes about the first 5 episodes of the US one. It’s much better developed and the directors/producers of the US one make it as realistic as they can.. instead of, for example, the UK series Annie is well seen by normal people and it doesn’t show her character learn how to do things like pick things up, make tea, open the door. She simply just can. The US series makes a strong point to show Sally, the ghost, going through that hard transition of learning how to even simply leave her house; even more so move things or make tea. The plots are extremely similar and in some aspects identical but the only real difference is the re-adaptation of the characters and how well developed the writers of the US version strived to make them. 
Ultimately, the UK one is amazing and directed so well that you can tell most scenes have an artistic or dramatic stitched in meaning with what’s going on WHILE the US version is more realistic (if these creators existed), relatable,  and entertaining.

Though again, warning, the US version really did take things from the UK version that are almost identically. The US version is simply just better written and developed.. and a lot more sexual.

Comment: I like this answer better than the others.

Answer (score 2):

They're fairly similar, but the US version has accelerated and edited/trimmed some of the plot points of the UK series.

Comment: Is it possible to expand on that a bit?

Comment: Trimmed?  The US version has twice the number of episodes...  (The difference in lengths of episodes makes up for some of it, but not all of it)

Answer (score 2):

It's still early to tell as the US version is only in it's second season but it does seem to be varying quite a bit from the UK series in it's second season. Of course it starts out with the basic premise and the first season has many comparable episodes to the original. All of the characters have different names and slight changes to their origins for the most part. The best way to watch at first may be to fast forward through parts of these episodes so you don't compare to much. But the actors Sam Witwer (Aidan the vampire) and Sam Huntington (Josh the werewolf) really brings this show alive. In my opinion Sally the ghost is just flat compared to the vibrancy of Annie but she gets better in some episodes especially in the second season.

In essence it's the same core characters but with slight differences that actually develop them into new characters. Except for the similar scenes and a few plot points you could almost believe that somehow in the US a vampire, werewolf and ghost stumbled upon the same idea as ones in the UK had.

The second season does seem to be going in another direction than the UK one for main season arcs. From comments I've seen on i09 from people that have followed both shows and they really do start to depart quite a bit which means now that it's in it's second season it's really starting to become it's own show. The first season did set a good tone and has enough differences in pacing and episode plots that it should be enjoyable to catch up and start in on season 2.

Answer (score 2):

- The US version has less swearing in it than the UK version.
- The little boy who gets turned into a vampire is a lot different; In the UK, Mitchell turns him and he went to leave with his mum (as a vampire) whereas in the US, Aiden didn't turn him it was someone else and he ended killing him in the end
- In the US version, they downplayed the whole "paedo" plotline
- In the UK version George didn't have a sister but in the US version he did
- The way that Sally/Annie died was very similar (but different) and Sally meets more ghosts than Annie

Personally, I think the US version is way better than the UK.

Answer (score 0):

The UK version is so much better, the acting is far better and it is much more gritty and the reactions of the characters in regard to the various situations they find themselves in is much more realistic. Perhaps the US version is slightly better budgeted but this really doesn't make the actual content any better, it is very very similar to the UK plot line, the first couple of episodes certainly have almost exactly the same themes and the screenplay is even almost identical- with Mitchell/Aiden's past etc.

Answer (score 0):

I vastly preferred the US version, particularly after the 1st season where significant divergence took place. Sally, in particular, was a vast improvement over Annie... Also, the guy who plays the US Werewolf could have a great career in standup comedy.

I also found the tone of the US version to be way more optimistic. I just don't enjoy watching brooding Europeans. As far as the person who mentioned a Hollywood feel: well, it does seem slickly produced. But the writers chose not to set/film the series in Los Angeles. Really, I get sick of seeing that place on screen and I've heard enough people grumble about it to know I'm not the only one. The Boston setting (yes I know it was filmed in Canada) was terrific.

I've also met the actors of the US version at conventions and they are extremely nice, funny people.

P.S. I did think the UK Bishop was an entertaining fellow.

Comment: this is more of a review than an answer